# Keep typing between Typescript and ActionScript 3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to use Javascript object in parameter with Actionscript function bind with ExternalInterface.callBack method and get an instance of ActionScript class as parameter other than Array or Object ?

My purpose is to keep typing between Javascript and Actionscript.

```
//Javascript

var swfObject = document.getElementById('mySwfObject');

var user = {
    id : 1337,
    name : 'Foo',
    surname : 'BAR'
};

swfObject.myFunction(user);


//Actionscript 3

ExternalInterface.addCallBack("myFunction", myFunction);

// Now
private static function myFunction(user : Object)  : void
{

}

// With your help
private static function myFunction(user : UserDTO) : void
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass anything but generic-friendly data types, at least built-in. You'll have to create some additional processing on the both sides that converts generics into class instances and back.

Answer (score 0):

I think essential answer would be that while it's possible to relatively easy construct AS3 instance of specific classes form external data, for simple objects, you cannot just "keep typing" and threat this like single JS/AS3 program.

For example production of data in your class may depend on other AS3-environment specific condition.

You may want look at [registerClassAlias()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) method which is used to transfer data using [AMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)

And other concepts that me be useful in communication with external resources
(Hover over the links to see more info it's kind of long delay):

[JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) - slower and you don't produce class instace automatically (probably easier to use)

[SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

[URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html)